# How to read a csv column as list and not as a string in python?

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file in which one column is a list of tuples. But when I am reading it in python the list of tuples is read as a string object.

Answer (score 1):

Read csv using pandas, using following function

`pandas.read_csv()`

It will read list as string. To convert it into list use following function

```
import ast

ast.literal_eval()
```